# How to make Dropdown with input field in django form

Tags: python, django, forms, drop-down-menu, django-forms

I am a noob to django and python

I have a django form, it needs a dropdown menu with input field to enter the text which is not listed in dropdown. Is there any shortcut method for it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: **forms.py** is like this ->
`officeName = forms.ModelChoiceField(label='Office Name', queryset=officeList.objects.all().order_by('id'))`

Answer (score 0):

After so many searches in google i have found a solution for the issue.
Using **autocomplete** which is provided by the *javascript*

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).